# Postfix -- mandatory TLS encryption not working for port 25 "relay sending"

Tags: postfix

On my Postfix server I use port `465` for submission, and port `25` for relay (*"relay receiving"* and *"relay sending"*). I use port `993` configured in Dovecot for mail "retrieval".

When I was setting up Postfix I avoided configuring ports `25` & `465` inside `/etc/postfix/main.cf` which remains simple:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname -------> "HELLO!"
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.domain.eu
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, tekpi-eu, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydomain = domain.eu
mynetworks_style = host
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/
virtual_mailbox_domains = domain.eu
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailboxes
virtual_gid_maps = static:997
virtual_uid_maps = static:997
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
```

It seems more logical to individually configure ports `25` & `465` in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`.

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtp
  -o smtp_use_tls=yes
  -o smtp_tls_loglevel=1
  -o smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtp_tls_wrappermode=yes
# -o smtp_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
  -o smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
  -o smtp_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server-rsa.cert
  -o smtp_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/server-rsa.key
  -o smtp_tls_eccert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server-ecdsa.cert
  -o smtp_tls_eckey_file=/etc/ssl/private/server-ecdsa.key
#
  -o smtpd_use_tls=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
  -o smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
  -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server-rsa.cert
  -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/server-rsa.key
  -o smtpd_tls_eccert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server-ecdsa.cert
  -o smtpd_tls_eckey_file=/etc/ssl/private/server-ecdsa.key
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_use_tls=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
  -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server-rsa.cert
  -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/server-rsa.key
  -o smtpd_tls_eccert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server-ecdsa.cert
  -o smtpd_tls_eckey_file=/etc/ssl/private/server-ecdsa.key
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
...
...
...
```

AFAIK in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

- commands starting with `-o smtpd_` configure *inbound* connections
- commands starting with `-o smtp_` configure *outbound* connections

Furthermore parameters starting with `-o` applied after the line below only modify port `25`:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

Similarly parameters starting with `-o` applied after the line below only modify port `465`:

```
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

So as you can see I have configured a mandatory TLS on port `25` *outbound* connections but when I send email to Gmail, message is labeled with a warning saying: *"This message wasn't encrypted"*:

[image]

If I inspect email header, there is no sign of encryption in the first `Received` field:

```
Delivered-To: z.l@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a50:a414:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id u20csp5876423edb;
        Wed, 23 Dec 2020 10:04:30 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJz/H6LVTTELjEg4kyxfY5WvBpShW3zeBpEASR/dmz8FHcT8QBpRbaNbCdGaTON4PTFMXVds
X-Received: by 2002:a05:6402:366:: with SMTP id s6mr25548681edw.44.1608746670340;
        Wed, 23 Dec 2020 10:04:30 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1608746670; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=0GELxkiim2MQGGCIrMsuVfXIiuzCbPnx6q6q7Sxuhssnb6XxCc1dtmsdUCVaGorqL/
         NWMA9sBfBZkz2ZCb90AoAk4Tyi1YzYw3WVLblw2+xQkbq+JwuYwdAjEQj2i2EJlBI3Zk
         KyYC2zfZqMkWMNRL27bI6pYwNtRYM7FifUeKmxaGuGuXv+7KY9wkrv9LTGI3a/UN634r
         Mqhog1Em8L8uLys0tDlj9GB08ZO52pPw01vJNU1AXqwOeRVznF9FPwfzP6Pn1drc4cOM
         x2vA5NJ+TgguOhqhgTSMW1hQrhNpyku3bYRW9PKQChZdHMowtSotpldYy1sJCf/VYeuA
         6fGg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=content-language:content-transfer-encoding:mime-version:user-agent
         :date:message-id:subject:from:to;
        bh=ZnLGQleFTlvpbWbWBAKrwartxhkzwpbLw0l/ILVPQLo=;
        b=Lt/88Ansftfa790xIUJbRfnuHWadZtBq5QHPDlDjJeGLBlmrLiyfIlzG5xwZTkqZmY
         XPImCgNHC+JfBDOhTFbiyahI7OMMAJGJAZDrr8K60TCztYqKE4Gkr6SZ7h3nAZVjLE8Y
         QBr0NOHZSQkMac/3WKOU86NtPEJwIu53Is71ucdpvNvwj8U5XHDDK9zUw8rcO9XF9JL+
         VUXTOhHmpEqhFgZDq+ldLANLkML+Ix/qvAnyb6JSss+rfsJO0h3Q2nh/LSQzbTFeWBbq
         oGksWfsCX7L0cfSij1GLWwYJ+1RrT/UBdb9p6OIK7sV2IpzAFmLgdRHoV2XHuB3XYSDy
         8gyw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of z.l@domain.eu designates 2a01:4f8:211:2a4::2 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=z.l@domain.eu;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=domain.eu
Return-Path: <z.l@domain.eu>
Received: from mail.domain.eu ([2a01:4f8:211:2a4::2])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id j10si12321635ejf.404.2020.12.23.10.04.30
        for <z.l@gmail.com>;
        Wed, 23 Dec 2020 10:04:30 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of z.l@domain.eu designates 2a01:4f8:211:2a4::2 as permitted sender) client-ip=2a01:4f8:211:2a4::2;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of z.l@domain.eu designates 2a01:4f8:211:2a4::2 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=z.l@domain.eu;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=domain.eu
Received: from [192.168.64.100] (188-230-147-194.dynamic.t-2.net [188.230.147.194])
    by mail.domain.eu (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id B486F15A1315
    for <z.l@gmail.com>; Wed, 23 Dec 2020 19:04:29 +0100 (CET)
To: z.l@gmail.com
From: Z L <z.l@domain.eu>
Subject: TEST (mandatory TLS): domain --> gmail
Message-ID: <d5c06629-4135-1730-9b7e-376201125fa8@domain.eu>
Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2020 19:04:29 +0100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/78.6.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Language: en-US

CONTENT TEXT
```

There is no sign of encryption also when I send email to myself. Here is an example email source:

```
Return-Path: <z.l@domain.eu>
X-Original-To: z.l@domain.eu
Delivered-To: z.l@domain.eu
Received: from [192.168.64.100] (unknown [188.230.147.194])
    by mail.domain.eu (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 3BE6015A132B
    for <z.l@domain.eu>; Wed, 23 Dec 2020 23:03:15 +0100 (CET)
To: z.l@domain.eu
From: Z L <z.l@domain.eu>
Subject: TEST (mandatory TLS): domain --> domain
Message-ID: <7a064c84-28e1-562c-c8f7-e3c89dc325ad@domain.eu>
Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2020 23:03:14 +0100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/78.6.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Language: en-US

CONTENT TEXT
```

Mandatory TLS works on port `465`. What did I missconfigure so it won't work on port `25`? How can I fix this to have a mandatory TLS or oportunistic TLS on `25` *outbound* connections?

Comment: You do realize that the standard submission port is 587 - not 465? 465 is considered obsolete for TLS submissions. 465 is not an 'official' email port, but is an "alternative" port that requires -implicit- TLS/SSL > "Authenticated SMTP over TLS/SSL ("SMTPS")"<. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: @B.Shea It is plaintext that shall be considered obsolete, and port 465 that should be preferred. The unfortunate IANA situation was finally resolved in 2018, via [RFC 8314](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314).

Comment: Yes, @anx , and thanks. Agreed. My comment was rather poorly worded to begin with, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `smtp_` directives configuring outbound connections need to be in `main.cf`, not in `master.cf`. The latter deals exclusively with inbound connectivity.

Comment: I moved the configurations and at first it did not work with mandatory TLS. It works only with opportunistic TLS. This is a mistery to me as Google supports STARTTLS. Then why does mandatory TLS fail? One more thing.  Do you know where in the official documentation I can find a rule that commands for outbound connections belong in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and not in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`?

Comment: @71GA It is inherent in the nature of the configuration file. A specific statement to that effect would be redundant. As for implicit TLS, that is only done on port 465. Ports 587 and 25 use STARTTLS only.